# XPath selector for tag with specific descendant tags selects other tags

Tags: xpath

Given a document:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div>No span</div>
      <span>Target</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to select the `<div>` containing the `<span>`. However, when I use this selector:

```
//div[//span]
```

It matches both `<div>`s:

```
<div><div>No span</div><span>Target</span></div>   <-- what I wanted
<div>No span</div>                                 <-- this is also matched
```

I tested this on Google Chrome's Devtools, as well as several online XPath evaluators, so I assume this is the correct behavior.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix my selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> select the `<div>` containing the `<span>`

Use relative paths.

```
//div[.//span]
```

`//` starts from the document root. `.//` starts from the context element.

Predicates evaluate to true when the contained expression selects nodes. This means that `//div[//span]` is always true when there is a `<span>` anywhere in the document, in which case all `<div>`s in the document will be selected. `//div[.//span]` is only true when there is a `<span>` anywhere in the respective `<div>`.

If you mean *"has a `<span>` child"* (as opposed to *"has a `<span>` descendant"*) this will work:

```
//div[span]
```

which is a shorthand for this (to underline the difference between `/` and `//`):

```
//div[./span]
```